# How to add a custom shape in the beginning of terminal command-prompt?

Tags: command-line, customization

I have seen a lot of terminal with sweet shape in the beginning of terminal command-prompt, like this:

[image: command-prompt]

and i want to add a shape like this :

```
.....____________________ , ,__
....../ `---___________----_____] - - - - - - - - ░ ▒▓▓█D
...../_==o;;;;;;;;_______.:/
.....), ---.(_(__) /
....// (..) ), ----"
...//___//
..//___//
.//___//
```

i know how to change text color and add a character at the end, but when i add the brev shape it give me an error when i open the terminal :

[image: my command-prompt]

so how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save whatever ascii art you want to add as a text file and name it say "ascii".

Open your home folder in nautilus and copy this file to your home folder.

Now if you press ctrl-h you will be able to see hidden files.

There will be a file .bashrc

Open it and add the following line at the end of the line...

cat ascii

Now save it and close it.

Run your terminal.

If every thing goes well, you should see what you intend to see...

there is a nice illustration with photos at the following link...

http://iloveubuntu.net/fancify-your-gnome-terminal-ascii-art

Comment: good trick and site, thanks, and here is my terminal --> http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/1671/menu005.png